# JQ field values shift to the left if a column value is unavailable

Tags: shell, awk, jq

I have a JSON object as shown below that I am trying to put in a table.

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Jay",
    "Age": "23"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jamie",
    "Age": "32"
  },
  {
    "name": "",
    "Age":"26"
  }
]
```

The problem is that if a column value is unavailable, the value from the next column slides into it.

For example, this is what happens for the 3rd value. How do I keep this from happening?

```
|  |name  | Age |
|--|----  | ----|
|1.| Jay  | 23  |
|2.| Jamie| 32  |
|3.|  26  |     |
```

My JSON is in a variable called `listofres`:

```bash
echo "$listofres" 
| jq -r '.[] | [.["name"], .["Age"]] | @tsv' 
| awk 'BEGIN { printf "%-2s %-20s %-20s\n", "","Name", "Age"; 
print "---------------------------------------"} 
{printf "%-2s. %-20s %-20s\n", (NR < 10 ? " " : "")NR, $1, $2}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

listofres='[
  {
    "name": "Jay",
    "Age": "23"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jamie",
    "Age": "32"
  },
  {
    "name": "",
    "Age":"26"
  }
]'

printf '%s\n' "$listofres" |
jq -r '.[] | [.["name"], .["Age"]] | @tsv' |
awk '
    BEGIN {
        FS = "\t"
        split(" Name Age",hdr,/[ ]/)
        for ( colNr in hdr ) {
            wids[colNr] = length(hdr[colNr])
        }
    }
    {
        $0 = NR "." FS $0
        for ( colNr=1; colNr<=NF; colNr++ ) {
            wid = length($colNr)
            wids[colNr] = (wid > wids[colNr] ? wid : wids[colNr])
            vals[NR,colNr] = $colNr
        }
    }
    END {
        for ( colNr=1; colNr<=NF; colNr++ ) {
            printf "|%-*s", wids[colNr], hdr[colNr]
        }
        print "|"

        for ( colNr=1; colNr<=NF; colNr++ ) {
            dashes = sprintf("%*s",wids[colNr],"")
            gsub(/ /,"-",dashes)
            printf "|%-*s", wids[colNr], dashes
        }
        print "|"

        for ( rowNr=1; rowNr<=NR; rowNr++ ) {
            for ( colNr=1; colNr<=NF; colNr++ ) {
                printf "|%-*s", wids[colNr], vals[rowNr,colNr]
            }
            print "|"
        }
    }
'
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
|  |Name |Age|
|--|-----|---|
|1.|Jay  |23 |
|2.|Jamie|32 |
|3.|     |26 |
```

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
cat file
[
  {
    "name": "Jay",
    "Age": "23"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jamie",
    "Age": "32"
  },
  {
    "name": "",
    "Age":"26"
  }
]
```

This is fairly trivial with [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.7.0/):

```
mlr --ijson --omd cat -n file    # markdown format
```

Prints:

```
| n | name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jay | 23 |
| 2 | Jamie | 32 |
| 3 |  | 26 |
```

That markdown renders as:

| n | name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jay | 23 |
| 2 | Jamie | 32 |
| 3 |  | 26 |

Or pretty print:

```
mlr --ijson --opprint cat -n file
n name  Age
1 Jay   23
2 Jamie 32
3 -     26
```

Or barred:

```
mlr --ijson --opprint --barred cat -n file 
+---+-------+-----+
| n | name  | Age |
+---+-------+-----+
| 1 | Jay   | 23  |
| 2 | Jamie | 32  |
| 3 |       | 26  |
+---+-------+-----+
```

You can also use Miller to deal with the JSON with your awk as written (with the only modification to use `\t` as IFS):

```
mlr --j2t -N cat file | awk -F "\t" '
BEGIN { printf "%-2s %-20s %-20s\n", "","Name", "Age"; 
print "---------------------------------------"} 
{printf "%-2s. %-20s %-20s\n", (NR < 10 ? " " : "")NR, $1, $2}'
```

Prints:

```
   Name                 Age                 
---------------------------------------
 1. Jayson               23                  
 2. Jamie                32                  
 3.                      26
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your invocation of `awk`.  Since you've used `@tsv`, you'll need to use `awk -F\\t ...` or equivalent.